# How to validate the DateTime of MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm format?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I am using MaskedEditExtender for entering a datetime.  I am unable to figure out how to validate it.

Is there any Regular Expression for validating dates along with time MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm

or any Javascript function ??

Comment: Try taking it up from here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

The website explains how to modify the regular expression to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THis will solve your issue:

```
^(([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])/[1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$
```

Comment: Again One more issue, if i give wrong format its showing error message ,but for empty time its not showing errormsg..

Comment: @Lakshmitha, I,ve updated my regular expression. Please try it out and let me know if any issue..

Comment: @Harun,Thanks.Its working now. But U've given the dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM format. I need MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM format only. I've tried lot to edit that expressing to change into MM/dd ,i couldt get. how to edit? Will u plz explain?

Comment: @Lakshmitha, Oh! sorry for the wrong updation. I've updated the exprss once again. I checked this for the format. Hope this will work for you..

Comment: It's actually necessary to escape the slashes. This is what actually works in this case: `^(([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])\/[1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$`

Answer (score 5):

Javascript has [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

it takes US formatted date of `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and with that format it works in all browsers I have tested: Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Edge

```js
console.log(new Date(Date.parse("03/25/2022 12:00")))
```

will return 10th September 2011 at noon

Comment: From Mozilla: "It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated)."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: @KelseyHannan With the date format I suggest, it works in all browsers I have. Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Edge

Answer (score 2):

And just in case you want the regular expression, this should work:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wteydsd6.aspx) (there are also [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) and [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s47fcc.aspx) equivalents).

If the string does not represent a valid `DateTime` it will not parse.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, 
                                          "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The above will throw an exception if the value is not parseable. Use the `Try` variant if you want to avoid the chance of the exception being thrown - this requires an `out` parameter and testing the return value of the function for success.

Comment: Based on the fact that the OP asked for "any Javascript function", I don't think C# code will be useful. It looks like OP needs client-side validation.

Comment: @Gabe - The OP did tag the question with C#, hence my answer. The question also appears to me to be asking about parsing - not necessarily using JS.

Comment: It appears as though the OP has written their ASP.NET page in C#, but is looking for client-side validation. Considering they asked for a regular expression or Javascript function, I removed the C# tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex:

```
^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\/([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-2][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
```

gives this result:

> 03/03/2021 02:12

Answer (score -1):

You may try following Function that Validates date in **"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"** format

```
    function ValidateDate(dt) {
        try {
            var isValidDate = false;
            var arr1 = dt.split('/');
            var year=0;var month=0;var day=0;var hour=0;var minute=0;var sec=0;
            if(arr1.length == 3)
            {
                var arr2 = arr1[2].split(' ');
                if(arr2.length == 2)
                {
                    var arr3 = arr2[1].split(':');
                    try{
                        year = parseInt(arr2[0],10);
                        month = parseInt(arr1[1],10);
                        day = parseInt(arr1[0],10);
                        hour = parseInt(arr3[0],10);
                        minute = parseInt(arr3[1],10);
                        //sec = parseInt(arr3[0],10);
                        sec = 0;
                        var isValidTime=false;
                        if(hour >=0 && hour <=23 && minute >=0 && minute<=59 && sec >=0 && sec<=59)
                            isValidTime=true;
                        else if(hour ==24 && minute ==0 && sec==0)
                            isValidTime=true;

                        if(isValidTime)
                        {
                            var isLeapYear = false;
                            if(year % 4 == 0)
                                 isLeapYear = true;

                            if((month==4 || month==6|| month==9|| month==11) && (day>=0 && day <= 30))
                                    isValidDate=true;
                            else if((month!=2) && (day>=0 && day <= 31))
                                    isValidDate=true;

                            if(!isValidDate){
                                if(isLeapYear)
                                {
                                    if(month==2 && (day>=0 && day <= 29))
                                        isValidDate=true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(month==2 && (day>=0 && day <= 28))
                                        isValidDate=true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(er){isValidDate = false;}
                }

            }

            return isValidDate;
        }
        catch (err) { alert('ValidateDate: ' + err); }
    }
```