# Validate date and time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, datetime

I have a jQuery datetime calendar which displays date time in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

I would need to validate both the date and time and return false if it's invalid.

The following code works fine for Date alone in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but I also want to add to validate time in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Could any please help?

```
var tbSCReferralDateTime = $("#<%=tbSCReferralDateTime.ClientID %>").val().trim();
        if (tbSCReferralDateTime.length > 0) {
            var chkReferralDateTime = isDate(tbSCReferralDateTime);
            if (chkReferralDateTime == false) {
                alert('invalid date time');
                proceed = 0;
            }
        }

 function isDate(txtDate) {
     var currVal = txtDate;
     var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
     var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern);
        if (dtArray == null)
            return false;
        dtDay = dtArray[1];
        dtMonth = dtArray[3];
        dtYear = dtArray[5];

        if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
            return false;
        else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
            return false;
        else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31)
            return false;
        else if (dtMonth == 2) {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap))
        return false;
        }
     return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you [[How to validate the DateTime of MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314305/how-to-validate-the-datetime-of-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-format][1])

[1]: "How to validate the DateTime of MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm format?"

Comment: I am very bad at Regex. Struggling to convert to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format.